# Securing ReST calls from same application

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I built a ReST service using Jersey in my custom java web application, Spring not used.
I want to use the service to get data for jQuery ajax calls from a jsp.

I have the service working, and the jQuery ajax calls are working.
I need to secure the service such that only users of the application can call the service.
I don't want a user to be able to copy the ajax url and later, from some other computer, call the service directly.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can done in same way you might have done for handling session for you JSP pages. Make your REST service URL session protected the way JSP page are protected.